# socket.io node.js invoke function on socket message

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I want to have a way to invoke a certain method on each and every socket message.

I tried to use something like, but only invokes once on initialize

```
io.use(function(socket, next){
  //do stuff. 
  //but only happens once when the user connects
});
```

How do I create a callback to be invoked on each and every socket request? In this method, I need to verify the JWT token. If invalid, I need to notify the client.

```
io.use(function(socket, next){
    jwt.verify(token, 'my secret key', function (err, decoded) {
      if (decoded) {
        // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
        socket.decoded_token = decoded;
      }
      next();
    });
});
```

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt.

Comment: That's what I am using. socketio-jwt only verifies the token on authenticate event. Once the user is authenticated, it doesn't check the token for any subsequent requests. if the token expires after the initial connect, socketio-jwt doesn't do broadcast the necessary "unauthenticated" event.